# R - Writing to Oracle from R and data types are too large

Tags: r, oracle, roracle

I am writing a table from R to the Oracle database, however, I keep getting datatypes that are too long, such as every character variable being VARCHAR2(2000).

```
#create iris dataframe
iris <- iris

#convert species to character for testing
iris$Species <- as.character(iris$Species)

#get variable types from data frame and recode to Oracle data types
variable_types <- iris %>% 
    summarise_all(typeof) %>%
    gather %>%
    mutate(new_type = case_when(value == "double" ~ "NUMBER",
                                value == "character" ~ "VARCHAR2(200)"))

#create named list for field.types
var_type_list <- as.character(variable_types$new_type)
names(var_type_list) <- variable_types$key

#verify types
print(var_type_list)

#write to db
rc <- dbWriteTable(con, "IRIS", iris, row.names=FALSE, field.types = var_type_list)
```

But when I check in Oracle, this is what I see for the lengths

```
Name         Null? Type           
------------ ----- -------------- 
Sepal.Length       NUMBER         
Sepal.Width        NUMBER         
Petal.Length       NUMBER         
Petal.Width        NUMBER         
Species            VARCHAR2(4000)
```

Am I using field.types incorrectly? Is there a better way to limit the length of the character variables?

Comment: I don't use Oracle, so this is from a different direction ... the `roracle` package has not been updated in two years, and while that itself is not a marker of problems, it might be that it is under-maintained. Are you able to shift to an ODBC connection (and the `odbc` package) and use that instead?

Comment: Side note: from [the source](https://github.com/cran/ROracle/blob/master/R/dbi.R#L239-L245) and an [empty search](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Acran%2FROracle%20field.types&type=code), perhaps `roracle` does not support `field.types` at all.

Comment: In my experience, it is often not possible to shift to another package to connect to an oracle database, and I also agree with @r2evans second comment. 
Maybe a way around is to first create it via `dbSendQuery` and then fill it with `dbWriteTable(... append = TRUE)` to preserve the datatypes you intend?

Comment: @clemenskuehn, are you saying that the [Oracle ODBC driver](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/releasenote-odbc-ic.html) is not stable or usable?

Comment: Reeza, while I've seen cases where the ODBC-based connections were slightly (very slightly) slower than the native connections, I've rarely seen "standard database use" affected by the change between native and ODBC-based connection types. Unless clemenskuehn comes back with something, I do suggest that it is worth a try at least to help troubleshoot whether it is `DBI::dbWriteTable` (and its methods), the database, or something else.

Comment: @r2evans, sorry, I did not mean that the ODBC drive is not stable or usable, but that often, connections to Oracle databases are made in a corporate environment where not every user is able to change from the package that IT has defined as the package to use to connect to databases.

Comment: Very good point @clemenskuehn, yes you are right. I'm hoping OP is able to try that shift, it seems that Oracle's native driver for R is lacking ...